# Show only one or two lines of a buffer

Tags: window, lines

I need to check numbers in a buffer each on a line against an external paper sheet

To make this easier I would like to make the window very narrow to see only *one* (or max. *two*) lines. However `shrink-window` stops at *three* lines.

Any way to overcome this limitation of `shrink-window`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows one line of content and the modeline for me:

```
(setq window-safe-min-height 0)
(setq window-min-height 0)
```

I would love to have a way to make the content completely collapse for an acme editor style. Sadly I haven't found the way.

Comment: How cool is this! I didn't know about `window-safe-min-height`. Just read the doco though. It says: "_The absolute minimum number of lines of any window. Anything less might crash Emacs._", so with `(setq window-safe-min-height 0)` I might live on the edge... 

Comment: Yeah, `(setq window-safe-min-height -1)` kind of does what I want, but sometimes the modelines merges into eachother :)

Comment: You kinda *did* know about `window-safe-min-height` because it was mentioned in the earlier answer, and you commented on it ;)  I wonder if the behaviour around minimum values has changed since then.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `window-min-height`

> The minimum total height, in lines, of any window.  The value has to
> accommodate one text line, a mode and header line, a horizontal scroll
> bar and a bottom divider, if present.  A value less than
> ‘window-safe-min-height’ is ignored.  The value of this variable is
> honored when windows are resized or split.

I found this with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-variable`
<kbd>RET</kbd> `height` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: With this variable I was able to shrink the window to **two** lines, but not to **one** line.

Comment: This is true, even if I set `window-min-height` to 1 (and `window-safe-min-height` is 1 as well).

Comment: The minimum is one editing line **plus** whatever additional lines are needed to display those other items.  If you have none of the other items (including disabling the mode line!) then you can have a window which is *just* that one single editing line.  (I just tested this in Emacs 26.3 in a terminal.)

Comment: You are correct: **without** mode line I do get the window down to 1 _content_ line. However, **with** mode line this doesn't seem to be possible: I always end up with two _content_ lines. Very strange!

Answer (score 1):

Would it suit your purpose if you had a command which searched for the next line in the buffer which has a number in it and then showed you just  that line?

```
(defun go-to-next-line-with-number ()
  (interactive)
  (widen)
  (unless (bobp)
    (end-of-line))
  (when (search-forward-regexp "[0-9]" nil 0)
    (save-excursion
      (narrow-to-region (progn (beginning-of-line) (point))
                        (progn (end-of-line) (point))))))
```

Assign this command to a key, then go to the beginning of the buffer. Calling this command will go to the first line with a number and show you only this line. When you have done whatever editing you need to do to this line, call it again to go to the next line with a number and so on until you reach the end of the buffer.

If this is close but not precisely what you need, tell me more exactly what would help.